# Read name and values of node using value of attribute in PHP XPATH

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using **PHP DOM XPATH**. I have XML structure as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:rank="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <rank:one year = "2015">99</<rank:one>
    <rank:two year = "2014">128</rank:two>
    <rank:three year = "2015">27</rank:three>
</root>
```

where I want to get **name and value of node where year is 2015**

expected output is rank:one -- 99 and rank:three -- 27
I tried to write xpath query as

```
$xpath->query('//root/[@year="2015"]');
```

I am not getting what should be xpath expression in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression should be

```
$xpath->query('//root/*[@year="2015"]');
```

Then you can use `name()` and `text()` to get its name and value, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I want.

Comment: please do not reject suggested edits like https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17296854. We're trying to improve StackOverflow, so even minor good edits should be approved. Otherwise you're leaving undesirable noise on the post. To judge if it is desirable, you could ask yourself "_would I approve a suggestion to *add* thank you?_" Alternatively, if you really want to decline someone for a "too minor" edit (which, again, you shouldn't), then use "reject and edit" and re-apply the minor edit to avoid leaving the noise on the post.